# Software for performance tests on an http server

Tags: performance, testing

I have developped a HTTP web service which is queried by smartphone. I want to test the performances of all this service containing :

- A java server (java 6, java + play framework)
- A database (Mysql 5.1.41)
- A Linux (ubuntu) server (kernell 2.6.32)

I have tried leading test campaigns using python scripts with many threads or sequential tests. But it's hard to have conclusions...
I want to be able to have the maximum number of request per second for my service, the average time for each request... complete dashboards displaying a lot of information

I can do many scripts to test that but I am shure that well-known softwares permits to conduct these tests. Ideally these softwares could also display information about where I loose time ...

Do you have hints ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some tools I've used for HTTP benchmarking

- [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)
- [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home)
- [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)

Of these, JMeter is probably best for the situation you describe.   All of these display a lot of information, but won't explain where you lose time.

For that, I'd suggest a profiler such as [JVisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) (comes with the JDK) or [YourKit](http://yourkit.com/).  From a profile you can observe where you spend the most time and focus on optimizing that.

Comment: Additionally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038515/tool-suggestion-for-load-testing-a-simple-web-page-with-submit-button/7280395#7280395