# Tool suggestion for load testing a simple web page with submit button?

Tags: load-testing

I've written a simple order application that consists of a 1 page order-form containing a set of input fields and a submit button. The order form is loaded by invoking a URL (with data being passed via POST):

http://localhost:8080/orderform.jsp

The input fields of the order-form are populated with the POST data and whilst the form is loading there some server side processing taking place e.g. retrieving data from a database. Once the page has loaded and the submit button is clicked further server side processing takes place to process the order and then a receipt page is displayed to the user.

I need a way to load test this simple process in order to ascertain the maximum throughput of the server.

Any tool suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I always tend to find these kinds posts useful at some level, despite their being closed with-prejudice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this relatively easy way of load testing I would recommend [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

While jmeter is ok, it's really weak in the analytics and parameterization area. If you want something free but enterprise-class, I'd recommend CloudTest Lite from SOASTA. It gives you the fastest way to create realistic scenario on the market, real-time analytics (!) and best of all, it's free.

You can download it and give it a try here: http://www.soasta.com/cloudtest/lite/

Fred

Comment: If you promote your product in an answer, you need to disclose your affiliation with the product in the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a trivial test using our product, [Web Performance Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/load_testing_tool.html). You didn't mention a budget and our product is not free.  However the free version will run 10 simultaneous users and if you reduce the think time, you can push a lot of transactions using the free version.

If you need something free, JMeter, Grinder and OpenSTA are popular options. You'll spend a lot more time learning the tools and setting up the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I ve wrote one very simple tool cause i didn't want to use any browser based tool. 
Biggest problem is i also wanted to stress test it locally, like hitting localhost.
Maybe you will also find it useful:

https://github.com/georgekosmidis/WebStressTool

*Uses Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool v2.3.1757674*